# Laravel&mongo DB

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

When I run the Mongodb driver I get this error:

> {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 1):
>   Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in
>   /var/www/lms/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php:87

How can I solve it?

Comment: composer require mongodb/mongodb

Comment: how are you running this query?

Comment: when I request to my web application get 503 response,  so I run this   tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: install mongodb extension